# Sylow subgroups of $\text{SL}_2(q)$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $p,q$ be primes such that $p$ is a divisor of $|\text{SL}_2(q)|=(q-1)q(q+1)$.
Hence $\text{SL}_2(q)$ admits non-trivial Sylow subgroups.
I am interested in the isomorphism type of the $p$-Sylow.
From what I understand, if $p<q$ are odd primes, then a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $\text{SL}_2(q)$ is cyclic.

However, in the case $p=2$ or $p=q$, I am not sure.

I tried to use Suzuki paper(http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372591?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), but it is rather complicated and I hoped there is an easier approach.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You may find the discussion of Sylow-$2$ subgroups $SL_2(q)$ in *Finite Groups-Gorenstein*, p.42-44.

Answer (score 5):

${\rm SL}(2,q)$ has a unique element of order $2$, namely $-I_2$. So the same applies to its Sylow $2$-subgroups. There is theorem that the only $2$-groups with this property are cyclic and generalized quaternion. Since the Sylow $2$-subgroups are not cyclic, they are geenralized quaternion.

Comment: The last statement is unclear to me. (I mean: if you write *Since Sylow-2 subgroups are not generalized quaternion, they are cyclic*, then also I didn't see why it is not true. In short, the *reasoning* is unclear to me.)

Answer (score 3):

We know that the group $SL_2(3)$ has $Q_8$ as $2$-Sylow-subgroup, which certainly is not a cyclic group - see [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_special_linear_group:SL%282,3%29). This is the case $p=2$, $q=3$, satisfying  $p\mid (q-1)q(q+1)$.

Edit: For odd primes $p$, every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $SL(2,q)$ is indeed cyclic (see [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jedyang/qual/groups.pdf), G6f3 c)).

Comment: I said it was cyclic when both $p,q$ are odd primes.

Comment: You also said "However, in the case $p=2$ I am not sure". Hence my example.

Comment: OK, sorry and thanks for your example. Do you know what happens in the case where $p=q$ is an odd prime?

Comment: The group $SL_2(q)$ clearly has a cyclic subgroup of order $q-1$ as the subgroup of diagonal matrices, and a cyclic subgroup of order $q+1$ that we get as the intersection of $SL_2(q)$ and the cyclic group $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}^*$ of the quadratic extension field (viewed as a subgroup of $GL_2(q)$. Therefore for $p>2$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup is cyclic. Even if a higher power of $p$ happens to be a factor of either $q-1$ or $q+1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks. But is it also true in the case $p=q$ is an odd prime?

Comment: @OfirSchnabel The Sylow $q$-subgroups of $SL_2(q)$ are cyclic and conjugate to the subgroup of upper unit-triangular matrices: $\begin{bmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @DavidHill Thanks a lot.